# Copy user document to another collection when user document is modified using trigger or hook

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

In meteorJS, I want to copy values inside the users collection to another collection using a trigger. So whenever the user collection is modified, the 2nd collection should also be updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [matb33:collection-hooks](https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks) package.

You can define the equivalent of *triggers* for inserts:

```
B = new Mongo.collection('b');
Meteor.users.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  var emails = doc.emails;
  B.insert({_id: doc._id, emails: emails}); // for example
});
```

As well as updates:

```
Meteor.users.before.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
  modifier.$set = modifier.$set || {};
  modifier.$set.modifiedAt = Date.now();
});
```

Hooks can run before or after events depending on your needs.

Comment: So I dont understand one thing, I want to copy data from say table A to table B. So i need to add tableA.before.insert(//data) but where am I refereing to table B here? and also what is userId, doc

Comment: `userId` is the `_id` of the user who is triggering the event. `doc` is the document that is being manipulated. You would refer to the other collection directly in the function that you are calling from the event. I'll rework the example a bit.